# Did the Obama Administration have an official National Security Strategy?

Tags: united-states, fake-news, national-security

[This Fox News opinion piece](http://www.foxnews.com/opinion/2018/04/09/president-trumps-most-overlooked-achievement-realistic-coherent-national-security-strategy.html) is largely centered around the following quote:

> "it had been over a decade since we’ve had an official [National Security Strategy](http://nssarchive.us/) to guide policy and spending priorities.
>   But President Trump got it done in his first year in office."

The hyperlink in the above quote block was the actual hyperlink included in the article, which links a National Security Strategy Archive that features [the Obama administration's 2015 National Security Strategy](http://nssarchive.us/national-security-strategy-2015/) two lines below the most recent strategy from the Trump administration.

Is there some technicality I'm missing here? Otherwise this seems like blatant lying.

Comment: Technically, it appears to be correct. But realistically it's nonsense. National security is often a bilateral endeavor. Russia, Iran, North Korea and China all pose different security challenges to the US. So a blanket policy is bound to be deficient. The fact that Trump got the official policy done and Obama didn't doesn't seem like a good measure of national security strategy, even for budgeting purposes.

Comment: Like the national security archive link you posted says (paraphrasing): *The National Security Strategy Report is required by law, but the White House often submits it late or not at all.*

Comment: Nitpick: this is not a "Fox News Article". It's an opinion page (as you can see if you hover over URL)

Comment: Yes, most of Fox News is opinion.

Comment: As much fun as it is to make fun of fox news, I think @Michael_B nailed it.   It's a technicality that should be submitted, that Fox news is calling a definitive policy.  Similar to when the democrats didn't submit a budget during Obama's first few years of the presidency.   It didn't really change anything, not submitting a budget.  The budget just continued from the previous year, but people who didn't like democrats were able to say "we don't have a budget, how irresponsible".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it seems that the author of the article is just completely incorrect, as the Obama administration produced a national security strategy in 2010 and 2015.

However, we can't say whether or not they're *lying*, because it's possible they didn't do any basic research and thus aren't intentionally making a false statement.

---

**National Security Strategies:** The [2015 one](http://nssarchive.us/national-security-strategy-2015/) was already mentioned in the question, and [here is the one from 2010](http://nssarchive.us/NSSR/2010.pdf). So, even if we ignore the 2015 strategy, it had still been less than a decade since this version was made.

However, if we ignore both of the Obama administration's security strategies, then I suppose it had been more than a decade since [the Bush administration's last one in 2006](http://nssarchive.us/NSSR/2006.pdf).

**National Military Strategies:** I tried to give them the benefit of the doubt and assumed they meant National *Military* Strategy, rather than *security*, but it turns out that's 1 year more wrong. Here's the [one from 2015](http://www.jcs.mil/Portals/36/Documents/Publications/National_Military_Strategy_2015.pdf), which includes the line "Since the last National Military Strategy was published in 2011...". The 2011 document [can be found here](https://www.army.mil/e2/rv5_downloads/info/references/NMS_Feb2011.pdf).

Comment: in the Fox News opinion section it seems possible that "we" might mean only Republicans.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt: I thought about that, which is why I included the one from 2006, but nothing in the article made me think the author's talking about anything except the government as a whole, or at least the executive branch of it.